# debug file in order to make a confirmation page ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm still new to ruby on rails. I need to make a confirmation page that displays all data.

here is my form

```
<%= form_tag(email_path, method: :post ) do %>
  <dl class="cf">
    <dt class="required">name</dt>
    <dd><%= text_field_tag(:name, "", class: 'input_text full') %></dd>
  </dl>
  <dl class="cf">
    <dt class="required">company</dt>
    <dd><%= text_field_tag(:company, "", class: 'input_text full') %></dd>
  </dl>
  <dl class="cf">
    <dt class="required">tel</dt>
    <dd><%= text_field_tag(:tel, "", class: 'input_text tel') %></dd>
  </dl>
  <dl class="cf">
    <dt class="required">email</dt>
    <dd><%= text_field_tag(:email, "", class: 'input_text email') %></dd>
  </dl>
  <dl class="cf">
    <dt class="">commant</dt>
    <dd><%= text_area_tag(:commant, "", class: 'textarea') %></dd>
  </dl>
  <ul class="form_btn cf">
    <li class="submit"><%= submit_tag(t('.ultra_tech_form_title').html_safe) %></li>
  </ul>

  <% end %>
```

and here are my routes

```
get 'email',  to: 'pages#email'
post 'email', to: 'pages#email_confirm'
```

and here are my controllers

```
def email; end

  def email_confirm
    render plain: params[:post].inspect
  end
```

but seems that I'm not successful in debugging it. How can I debug the data?

Comment: _"i need to make a confirm file"_ - Define "confirm file".

Comment: a page that display all data that i submit it

Comment: i want to debug the data before go to confirmation page

Comment: What do you mean "debug" the data? As an end user, what do you want to see when you click submit on first page?

Comment: Try to install gem 'pry-rails' and debug this code just adding 'binding.pry' in the necessary place.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong place is there `render plain: params[:post].inspect`. You haven't any parameters with key `:post`. So, `render plain: params.inspect` will be working great.

About reason to do that: there no reason. You can install gem 'pry-rails' or read incoming parameters just from log file or from a live log in your console. For example:

```
Started POST "/email" for ....
Processing by PagesController#email_confirm as HTML
  Parameters: {...}
```

Also you can use byebug that included in rails default gemset:

```
def email_confirm
  byebug
  ...
end
```

In this place, you will have irb-mode with all code state at that moment in your console.

[More about debugging in rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html)